# How do I fix this error with kick command

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to make an kick command but i ran into this error but i couldnt find out how to fix it.
I tried giving permissions to the bot. And giving permissions to me but it all didnt work.
This is my code:

```py
@bot.command(name='kick', aliases=['Kick'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('What is the reason?')
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message')
    reason = msg.content
    description = f'''
    **Member:** = {member}
    **Responsible moderator:** {ctx.author.mention}
    **Reason:** {reason}
    '''
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Kick', description=description)
    await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

This is the error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Guido/Desktop/yeet/overig/coding/discord bots/self coded/oden/code/Oden.py", line 80, in kick
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 489, in kick
    await self.guild.kick(self, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1627, in kick
    await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is that the bot does not have the permission to kick a user in that server. Make sure that the bot has the Kick Members permission. The bot having permission is the only thing that matters from the API's perspective

Comment: It has, It has 2 roles both with all permissions. :/

Comment: Does the person you are trying to kick have a higher top role than the bot? You cannot kick anyone who is not lower on the role hierarchy than you/is the server owner.

Comment: nope, the role with all the permissions this bot has is the highest in the server

Comment: The exception says the bot does not have permission to kick that person, so either the bot does not have the permission to kick anyone, or they do not have permission to kick that user in particular due to the user having higher or equal role heirarchies. Try manually removing all roles from the person you are trying to kick before kicking them. Note that you can never kick the owner of a server.

Comment: already tried that. and i am the owner of the server myself so

Comment: I think it was a glitch or something. I started the code today without changing anything and it worked. (-: